# Quadratic responsive html divs keeping aspect ratio

Tags: css, html, mobile

Basically I want to have four quadratic `divs` in a row.
But in the first row the first two squares are merged into a rectangle.
The size of the squares should fit automatically the size of the browser window. **Important**: Between the divs I want a little margin.

My **HTML**:

```
            <div id="service-wrapper">
                <div class="double-col"></div>
                <div class="single-col"></div>
                <div class="single-col"></div>

                <div class="single-col"></div>
                <div class="single-col"></div>
                <div class="single-col"></div>
                <div class="single-col"></div>

                <div class="single-col"></div>
                <div class="single-col"></div>
                <div class="single-col"></div>
                <div class="single-col"></div>  

            </div>
```

and my **CSS**:

```
    #service-wrapper
    {
        height: auto;
    }

    .single-col,
    .double-col
    {
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        height: 10%;
        border: 1px solid blue;
        padding: 2%;
        display: inline-block;
    }

    .single-col
    {
        width: 25%;
    }

    .double-col
    {
        width: 50%;
    }
```

Comment: Do you try something? Post some of your code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this solution to create  **quadratic** `div` elements, perfect for responsive web design.

See here: [JSFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7vbN5/11/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="columns">
    <div class="col double"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>

    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>

    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>  
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.col
{
    margin: 2%;
    background: #f00;
    float: left;
    width: 21%;   
}
.col:before
{
    content: "";
    display: block;
    padding-top: 100%;
}
.double
{
    width: 46%;
}
.double:before
{
     padding-top: 45.6%;
}
```

Read **[this](http://blog.brianjohnsondesign.com/maintain-aspect-ratio-for-html-element-using-only-css-in-a-responsive-design/)** article for more information.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a `float` property to the divs and let it be a `block` element instead of `inline-block`.

**[JSFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7vbN5/16/)**

I've changed your class names as well so you have a common class of `col` which assumes that every column will be single unless it is overridden with a `double` class. It basically means you have less markup and CSS to maintain as you see from my example.

**HTML**

```
<div class="columns">

    <div class="col double"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>

    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>

    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>  

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.col
{
    padding-bottom: 23%; /* padding-bottom = width value - 2 (1 each for margin top and bottom values */
    background: #f00;
    float: left;
    width: 23%;
    margin: 1% 1%;
}
.col.double
{
    width: 48%; /* width = .col width * 2 + 2 (1 each for margin left and right values */
}
```

Alternatively, here are some examples of JavaScript based masonary layouts which could extend the functionality of your blocks further.

- [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/)
- [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/)

Comment: I also want to have a margin between the squares. How can I realize that.

Comment: I've edited my answer so it includes a margin as well.